# Matplotlib: data not showing on the two sides in heatmap using x, y, z values stored in lists

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am trying to generate a heatmap using Matplotlib for the first time. I have values (z) for each x, y cells. Thanks to [this page](https://gist.github.com/teechap/9c066a9ab054cc322877), I think I am close to getting what I want but my plot does not show all the data. It is missing the 5th column and 5th row. Am I missing something?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# x, y data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

z = [
    [100, 500, 10, 50, 100],
    [200, 600, 100, 600, 200],
    [300, 700, 50, 700, 300],
    [200, 600, 100, 600, 200],
    [600, 200, 10, 50, 600]
    ]

x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

z = np.array(z)
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap = 'Blues')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x and y are the coordinates of the lines separating the cells (=the squares), not their centre.

So for 5*5 cells, there should be 6*6 x coordinates and 6*6 y coordinates.
Something like:

```
x = [0 ,1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [0 ,1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you want the labels to be in the centre, here's a trick:

```
x=[0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5]
y= x
z = [
    [100, 500, 10, 50, 100],
    [200, 600, 100, 600, 200],
    [300, 700, 50, 700, 300],
    [200, 600, 100, 600, 200],
    [600, 200, 10, 50, 600]
    ]
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.array(z)
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap = 'Blues')
plt.xlim([0.5,5.5])
plt.ylim([0.5,5.5])
```

[image: pcolormesh with nice labels]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I did not realize that the x, y coordinates were for lines separating the cells. Your answer solved my problem beautifully!